# Webex to Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, webex

Hello I am creating a bot in Webex for testing reasons.

I am using Visual Studio Code, Dialogflow, Google Sdk, and docker to create this.

If you would like to follow along the github repo is

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/spark#readme

looking at the main README.md,in the Deploying the Integration using Cloud Run I am having trouble understanding what they mean by PLATFORM, when i put in the path/relative path of my .json file into the Google SDK shell, I get an error of INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build: invalid image name. I am unsure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cloned the repo?

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations.git
```

There are several possible integrations. If you are integrating with webex, then your platform is spark.
Whenever they talk about "platform subdirectory name" they are also refering to spark, as that is the name of that folder in the root directory.